How to change React state variable inside a while loop?
I am new to React and web dev in general. I managed to find a workaround for my issue but the issue itself still baffles me. I am hoping for an in depth explanation or pointers to where I can learn more about this, thanks!
const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
const drawCard = async () => {
    while (score < 20) {
        const card = await deal(); //deal function fetches cards from deckofcards api
        const value = card.value; //syntax isn't correct but say I access it's int value
        setScore(score => score + value); //or setScore(score + value); both didn't work
        //other code, add to my deck etc...
    }
}

When I tried debugging this I found that the score doesn't update in the loop, I am guessing it has to do with the asynchronous nature or maybe some React event loop thing?
I managed to get this working by creating a temporary variable outside the while loop to store the value and then setScore the variable in one go and it works fine. But I am curious to why this doesn't work.

This is how React works under the hood. It batches state updates to prevent the component keeps rerendering which can affect your app performance. More on their documentation: https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#react-batches-state-updates

Just imagine,if the score is updated after function deal in every loop, the component will be rerender,then  a new while loop will be created, there will be more and more while loop,it's so photogenic, so react won't immediately update data in loop To avoid that,I wrote a demo  if this what you want.

Thanks! That makes a lot of sense, I'll need to look more into React in general, I didn't know that changing the state variables rerenders the component. I appreciate the code and the timer delay is perfect, thanks
